# give divs depth with css box-shadow property

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this effect:

[image]

SO far I have this but I cannot get the shadows correct and why do most examples have `rgb` instead of hex?

```css
div {
  margin: 16px 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #E6E6E6, 0px 0px 0px #E6E6E6, 0px 0px 0px #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>One</div>
<div>One</div>
<div>Three</div>
```

Comment: By using `rgba(...)` you can actually have control over the opacity of the box shadow ;)

Comment: I'm also having problems like this. It's always either too spreaded or too thick :p But I think that adding `border: 1px solid #E6E6E6; padding: 3px;` gives it a bit more depth

Comment: Maybe you can check [CSS-Shadow-Generator](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why using RGBA colors are more common with box-shadows is because then it will blend well with the background. By using a color, you might end up having a "glow" effect when the luminousity of the box shadow colour is higher (i.e. brighter) than the background.

To get the effect you want to achieve, it's actually quite easy:

1. You use a general box-shadow that is not offset at all, to give all 4 edges some kind of shadow
2. You use a second box-shadow that is offset by a few pixels, to give directionality of the shadow, which then gives a depth effect

Grocking the actualy opacity is mostly a trial-and-error thing. See proof-of-concept below:

```css
div {
  margin: 16px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div>One</div>
<div>One</div>
<div>Three</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a great job already. The only modification needed is to make a box-shadow that doesn't have a x or y offset and some more 'blur'.

**Basis usage:**

```
box-shadow: h-offset v-offset blur spread color;
```

More about the subject:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Or just use a generator!
https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

```css
div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #E6E6E6, 0px 0px 0px #E6E6E6, 0px 0px 0px #E6E6E6, 2px 2px 5px #E6E6E6, 0px 0px 0px #E6E6E6, 0px 0px 0px #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>One</div>
<div>One</div>
<div>Three</div>
```

Comment: Once you check the answer he is using margin two times.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(32,33,36,0.28);
border-color: rgba(223,225,229,0);
```

Comment: "_If you give a men a fish, he has food for one day, but if you teach him how to fish he has food each day._"